# UISearchDisplayController overlay positioning

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, search

I'm having a bit of difficulty with `UISearchDisplayController` and the positioning of it's grey overlay when building against iOS 7. This was working fine when building against iOS 6, but only seems to have

I have a `UIView` built into a base ViewController which needs to be shown on every page (reads "Hello thereAnother String") in the screenshot before. When I navigate to my view controller which includes the UISearchDisplayController, this is what I see:

[image]

This is fine and is what I'd expect to see. However, when I try to click on the view UISearchBar, this is what I see:

[image]

Note that the grey overlay is offset by the size of that `UIView` that I need to put in all screens of the application.

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

can you use custom category of UITextfield and override those Method the

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds; and 
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds ;
```

this problem occur from custome this method.

Comment: I should have outlined this in my original post, but the 'TextField' that you're seeing there is really a UISearchBar, so those methods are not available. At any rate, I don't believe altering the behaviour of the UISearchBar will have any impact on the grey overlay that I'm trying to reposition.